# Encoding basic instruction formats in MIPS

Tags: set, mips, basic

I'd like to figure out how to encode BASIC INSTRUCTION FORMATS referred to in the [MIPS Green Sheet](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61c/.../MIPS_Green_Sheet.pdf)
e.g. I'd like to encode the instruction `add $t0 $t1, $t2`.

I know that the Format is R; opcode will be 0x0; The Funct 0x20.

But how will I get the code for rs, rt, rd and shamt?

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

The link in the question is mangled.  It should be https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61c/resources/MIPS_Green_Sheet.pdf

If you look in the **REGISTER NAME, NUMBER, USE, CALL CONVENTION** box at the bottom right of page 1 of that PDF, you'll see that the registers with names `$t0` through `$t7` correspond to the registers numbered 8 through 15.  For the instruction you're interested in:

```
    add $t0, $t1, $t2
```

`$t0` is the destination register, specified by the `rd` field in the instruction.  Since `$t0` is register number 8, put `01000` into the `rd` field.

`$t1` and `$t2` are the source registers, specified by the `rs` and `rt` fields in the instruction.  Since `$t1` is register number 9 and `$t2` is register number 10, put `01001` into the `rs` field and put `01010` into the `rt` field.

`shamt` is not used in the `add` instruction, so fill that field with zeroes.

BTW, that Green Sheet is fine as a reminder of the nitty-gritty details of the instruction set, but something like https://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~franklin/64/lectures/mipsassemblytutorial.pdf will be more helpful if you're just getting started with the MIPS architecture.